# error TS2420: Class 'NgRedux<RootState>' incorrectly implements interface 'ObservableStore<RootState>'

Tags: linux, angular, ubuntu, redux

When I am going to compile or build angular application on linux (ubuntu) I am getting this issue:

**For Compilation:** ng serve

**For building:**   ng build --base-href=/dist/

**Error:**

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@angular-redux/store/lib/src/components/ng-redux.d.ts(10,31): error TS2420: Class 'NgRedux' incorrectly implements
>   interface 'ObservableStore'.   Property
>   '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type 'NgRedux' but
>   required in type 'ObservableStore'.

These above bash commands working well in my windows environment with same application, when I tried to run or build on Ubuntu it give me this error. This look like redux issue I have downgraded redux version
But it did’t worked for me, I have also tried each and every combination but this issue is not resolved on Ubuntu.

**Environment on Linux(Ubuntu) Machine**

**Node Version:** v8.10.0

**NPM Version:** 3.5.2

**Ng version:** 7.0.3

**Environment on Windows Machine**

**Node Version:** v8.11.3

**NPM Version:** 5.6.0

**Ng version:** 7.0.3

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/3466

Comment: @AndrewHill pupose solution i have tried but it did't worked in my case

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, and the following combination worked for me:

angular cli v9.1.6, redux v4.0.1, angular-redux/store V9

so maybe this?

`npm install --save redux@4.0.1`

`npm install --save @angular-redux/store@^9`

Answer (score 4):

Below commands also helped me to fix my problem.

npm install --save redux@4.0.1

npm install --save @angular-redux/store@^9

Error was:

ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular-redux/store" has missing dependencies:
 - redux-devtools-extension

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular-redux/store/components/ng-redux.d.ts:10:31 - error TS2420: Class 'NgRedux<RootState>' incorrectly implements interface 'ObservableStore<RootState>'.
  Property '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type 'NgRedux<RootState>' but required in type 'ObservableStore<RootState>'.

10 export declare abstract class NgRedux<RootState> implements ObservableStore<RootState> {
                                 ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/redux/index.d.ts:337:3
    337   [Symbol.observable](): Observable<S>
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[Symbol.observable]' is declared here.
node_modules/@angular-redux/store/components/dev-tools.d.ts:3:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'redux-devtools-extension'.

3 import { EnhancerOptions } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
```